# c# why can't we override static property ? (how can high level classes call base class method with high level data)

Tags: c#, inheritance

My question is probably not well phrased and it's probably a dupe but here I go

```
class person {
    protected static string request = "select * from person where gender in ('male','female')";
    public string sharedmethod()
    {
        return "the request is" + request;
    }
}

class man:person
{
    override protected static string request = "select person.*,man.* from person,men where mytype in ('male') ";
    DateTime dateOfFirstCar;
}

class woman:person
{
    override protected static string request = "select person.*,woman.* from person,women where mytype in ('female') ";
    DateTime dateOfFirstITBAG;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (new person().sharedmethod() == new man().sharedmethod())
            Console.Write("too bad query is the same in base and dervide class");
    }
}
```

A man is a person
A woman is a person
Person,man,woman exist in my database but need different queries

I don't want to duplicate those queries so I thought it was a good idea to store them in a static property in each class.

I got some low level stuff (not figured there) that lie in the base class (coz I don't want to duplicate) and I wanted inherited classes to call base class method with the context of the herited classes

I want  man.[inherited]somemethod() to execute person.somemethod() but with variables coming from man

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a non-static property covering the static string, and reference that property instead:

```
class person {
    private const string request = "select * from person where gender in ('male','female')";
    protected virtual string Request {get {return request;}}
    public string sharedmethod() {
        return "the request is" + Request;
    }
}

class man:person {
    private const string request = "select person.*,man.* from person,men where mytype in ('male') ";
    protected override string Request {get {return request;}}
    DateTime dateOfFirstCar;
}

class woman:person {
    private const string request = "select person.*,woman.* from person,women where mytype in ('female') ";
    protected override string Request {get {return request;}}
    DateTime dateOfFirstITBAG;
}
```

Comment: @frenchone I missed that part. You need to make the property `virtual` instead of `abstract`, add an implementation in the `person` class, and add an `override` to the derived implementations.